# video-react attribute width and height is not working

Tags: reactjs, video.js, video-reactjs

As per this [doc](https://video-react.js.org/components/player/)

We can add width and height for player in attribute

```
<Player playsInline width={100} height={50}>
<source src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer_hd.mp4"/>
<ControlBar>
    <PlaybackRateMenuButton rates={[2,1.5,1]} order={7.1} />
    <VolumeMenuButton disabled />
</ControlBar>
</Player>
```

But these don't work ..
So, did i doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Video Width** and **Height attribute** is effective only if we set `fluid` as `false`

```
<Player playsInline fluid={false} width={100} height={50}>
      <source src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer_hd.mp4"/>
      <ControlBar>
          <PlaybackRateMenuButton rates={[2,1.5,1]} order={7.1} />
          <VolumeMenuButton disabled />
      </ControlBar>
    </Player>
```

They've updated this in there [doc](https://github.com/video-react/video-react/commit/aaa8e4333c248daefe98dfa285d0e19da0460078) too.