# 'video-react' doesn't let me change height and width of my video

Tags: reactjs, video, jsx

I have a big video that I want to put on my page, when I try to make it smaller it doesn't let me. I'm using the 'video-react' library. Here's my code:

```
<Player fluid={false} width={"330px"} height={"500px"} id="videoplayer" className="react-player" autoPlay={true} loop muted 
ref={player => {
 this.player = player;
  }} videoId="video-1">
      <source src={this.state.playerSource} />       
      

    </Player>
```

I tried multiple variations and nothing works. Please help.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51317145/18885543) answer your question? Also, according to the [docs](https://video-react.js.org/components/player/), the `width` and `height` attributes should be numbers, not strings

Comment: I tried importing the css but it gets me this error "./src/components/Main.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '../node_modules/video-react/dist/video-react.css'" no matter what I put inside the brackets of width and height I guess without this css I can't change it. Do yo know what could I do?